# How can I get all attribute bindings for a program in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I have a WebGL application in which some attributes are bounded to a program via getAttribLocation and some attributes are bounded to a program via bindAttribLocation.

Is there a way in which I can get a mapping of all string names to attrib indices/values for a program? Also, at which point can I do this? I think getAttribLocation can be called after a program is linked, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Here's an excerpt of code from my [Cubes](https://github.com/kpreid/cubes/blob/master/util.js), which both binds some attributes and looks up the indices of others:

```
for (var attribName in boundAttribLocations) {
  var index = boundAttribLocations[attribName];
  if (typeof index === "number") {
    gl.bindAttribLocation(program, index, attribName);
  } else {
    if (typeof console !== "undefined") {
      console.warn("Enumerable non-number", attribName, "in boundAttribLocations object", boundAttribLocations);
    }
  }
}

gl.linkProgram(program);

if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  throw new Error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
}

var i, name;
var attribs = Object.create(boundAttribLocations);
for (i = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  name = gl.getActiveAttrib(program, i).name;
  attribs[name] = gl.getAttribLocation(program, name);
}
```

If I recall correctly, the inheritance of `boundAttribLocations` (`Object.create`) is so that `attribs` will contain valid locations for all bound attributes, including those not used by the current shader, which GL will not enumerate with `getActiveAttrib`.

Answer (score 3):

You can query all the attributes like this

Assuming `program` is a shader program that was successfully linked with `gl.linkProgram` then

```
const numAttribs = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES);
for (let ii = 0; ii < numAttribs; ++ii) {
  const attribInfo = gl.getActiveAttrib(program, ii);
  const index = gl.getAttribLocation(program, attribInfo.name);
  console.log(index, attribInfo.name);
}
```

Example:

```js
const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
attribute float extra;
void main() {
  // it's only important we use all the attributes so they don't get optimized
  // out. It's not important that this shader makes no sense since that's
  // not the point of this example.
  gl_Position = position + vec4(normal, 0) + color + vec4(texcoord, extra, 0); 
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1);
}
`;

const prg = createProgram(gl, vs, fs);
showAttributes(gl, prg);

function showAttributes(gl, program) {
  const numAttribs = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES);
  for (let ii = 0; ii < numAttribs; ++ii) {
    const attribInfo = gl.getActiveAttrib(program, ii);
    const index = gl.getAttribLocation(program, attribInfo.name);
    log("index:", index, "size:", attribInfo.size, "type:", glEnumToString(gl, attribInfo.type).padEnd(10), "name:", attribInfo.name);
  }
}

function createProgram(gl, vSrc, fSrc) {
  const vs = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vSrc);
  const fs = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fSrc);
  const p = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(p, vs);
  gl.attachShader(p, fs);
  gl.linkProgram(p);
  return p;
}

function createShader(gl, type, src) {
  const s = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(s, src);
  gl.compileShader(s);
  return s;
}

function glEnumToString(gl, value) {
  for (let key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === value) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return "0x" + value.toString(16);
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement("pre");
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: When requesting `gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES` what is a scenario where `if(!attribInfo)` might be true? As I understand your code a program will  not return anything that is not there, right?

Comment: Did you remove it from twgl.js?

Comment: Yes, but added some other checks